# HTTP post 400 bad request

Tags: android, post, android-asynctask

When I try to use my restTemplate.postForEntity I get a 404 bad request
What is my fault?

Code:

Servercaller:

```
public ServerError login(String username, String password) {
       User user = new User();
       user.setUsername(username);
       user.setPassword(password);

       try {
           String URL = "http://"+ipAddress+"/ProjectTeamF-1.0/service/login.json";
           Object[] params = new Object[]{URL,user};
           new login().execute(params);


       } catch (ResourceAccessException rae) {
           receivedUser = null;
           return ServerError.ServerNotFound;
       } catch (HttpServerErrorException hsee) {
           receivedUser = null;
           return ServerError.WrongData;
       } catch(RestClientException rce){
           receivedUser = null;
           return ServerError.WrongData;
       } catch (Exception e) {
           System.out.println("error " + e);
           receivedUser = null;
           return ServerError.OtherError;
       }
       return ServerError.NoError;
   }
```

AsyncTask:

```
public class login extends AsyncTask<Object[], Void, Void> {
public ServerCaller sc = ServerCaller.getInstance();
public User body;

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Object[]... params) {
    String message = "";
    try {
        HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        requestHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        HttpEntity<User> _entity = new HttpEntity<User>((User)params[0][1], requestHeaders);
        RestTemplate templ = new RestTemplate();
        templ.setRequestFactory(new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory());
        templ.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter());
        ResponseEntity<User> _response = templ.postForEntity(params[0][0].toString(), _entity, User.class); //null here in order there wasn't http converter errors because response type String and [text/html] for JSON are not compatible;
        body = _response.getBody();
        return null;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        message = e.getMessage();
        return null;
    }
}

@Override
   protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
   super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
   sc.setReceivedUser(body);
}
}
```

When I debug the program crashes at templ.postForEntity(). The error tells me that this is a 400 - bad request.

Thanks!

Comment: What happens when you visit that URL in your browser on the device/emulator?

Comment: @RaghavSood HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'GET' not supported

Comment: Is "ipAddress" your local machine, or a local net address? Are you trying to use an emulator or an actual device? If any of those are true you might want to check out how the Android emulator networking works: http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#emulatornetworking. (And Follow Raghav's advice, obviously it GET is not supported then try the CORRECT HTTP method. Use curl, or for the lazy, hurl.it, etc. Start with whether or not basic networking is in order.)

Comment: @BartLeemans : best way is first install [httprequester firefox plugin](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/httprequester/) and try to get data from service by using GET and POST request. then change your code according to request type

Comment: @CharlieCollins ipAddress is correct. I am using an actual device en i can access my webclient using the device's webbrowser. GET methods work perfectly, just the POST methods are crashing..

Comment: I was responding to your statement Bart: "HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'GET' not supported." If GET and POST work fine outside of Android then sure, disregard. For more help you might want to post the actual error, include trace, etc.